# Parsing Elmah error logs using a console application

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

In an effort to minimize time spent on reading error logs, I have created the following small plugin that will parse relevant information contained within Elmah error logs, and eventually produce an Excel spreadsheet. For the time being I am using a WriteLine to test. The issue I am facing is that inside the second `foreach` loop I am seeing a null reference exception in each of the node.attribute items. The expected outcome of this code is to produce a list of "attribute" values from within the `<error>` tag of each of the XML documents.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace ExcelSortingAutomation
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo Exceptions = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\ErrorsMay2017");
            FileInfo[] ExceptionFiles = Exceptions.GetFiles("*.xml");

            foreach (var exception in ExceptionFiles)
            {
                string xml = "<error></error>";
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(xml);


                foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//error"))
                {
                    string errorId = node.Attributes["errorId"].Value;
                    string type = node.Attributes["type"].Value;
                    string message = node.Attributes["message"].Value;
                    string time = node.Attributes["time"].Value;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2} = {3}", errorId, type, message, time);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, Why would the logs, which should be pulled and parsed by this point, not be receiving the Attribute values?

Edit 1: upon closer inspection, the XmlNode Node value is returning without "HasAttributes"

Comment: The line `string xml = "<error></error>";` should be replace with `string xml = File.ReadAllText(exception.FullName));`

Comment: @JamesCurran That worked pretty well. May I please ask you to set it as the answer so I may accept it?

Comment: I was expecting you to say "That line is just for the example. I read the file in my real code". Then I was going to say "then replace the <error></error> with some an actual snippet from the file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `string xml = "<error></error>";` should be replace with `string xml = File.ReadAllText(exception.FullName));`